# Arduino program wont work properly for some reason

Tags: arduino-nano

I have a arduino program that I wrote with my teammembers. We are working on a project and try to move a RC car. Here is our code.

```
int forward =12 ; //assign to correlating pin attached to TP06
int backward = 11; //assign to correlating pin attached to TP07
int left = 10; //assign to correlating pin attached to (left steer)
int right = 9; //assign to correlating pin attached to (right steer)

// TP09 & TP02 (don't remember which is left and right)

void setup() {
pinMode(forward, OUTPUT);
pinMode(backward, OUTPUT); 
pinMode(left, OUTPUT);
pinMode(right, OUTPUT);
}

void move_Forward() {
digitalWrite(forward, HIGH);
digitalWrite(backward, LOW);
}

void move_Backward() { 
digitalWrite(backward, HIGH);
digitalWrite(forward, LOW);
}

void turn_Left() {
digitalWrite(left, HIGH);
digitalWrite(right, LOW);
}

void turn_Right() {
digitalWrite(right, HIGH);
digitalWrite(left, LOW);
}

void stop_Completely() {
digitalWrite(forward, LOW);
digitalWrite(backward, LOW);
digitalWrite(right, LOW);
digitalWrite(left, LOW);
}

// loop will keep going while arduino has power
void loop() {
move_Forward();
turn_Left(); 
}
```

When we run this code, for some reason forward pin and left pins are becoming deactivated, which are the pin numbers 12 and 10. Like it does not supply voltage anymore for some reason. However right pin and backward pins, which are pins 9 and 11, which was not included in loop, works! I can run the RC car with these pins. I dont understand why this is the case. Shouldn't the left and forward pins work? If they are not working, how come? Sorry I am new to arduino programming language and its been very challenging for me and my group. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us your circuit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On many Arduinos, those pins (10-12) are shared with the ICSP header - are you programming/testing with it plugged in or unplugged? If plugged in, you might be affected by what you're plugged into.

Here's a useful pinout: http://t.co/MKtmCILSdj

Here's a Nano pinout: [image: Nano pinout]

Note that the ICSP is electrically connected to pins D11, D12 and D13 - so if you have something plugged into the ICSP header, you have something connected to those pins which might be causing your problem.

If you're programming via serial port (TX/RX) and have nothing connected to ICSP, then this isn't your issue. If that's a case, it's possible to fry a few pins on a Nano and have it still appear to mostly work - trying another couple of pins might tell you more. (For instance, try D4 and D5 instead of D10 and D12.)

Comment: My arduino is nano. And the problem is that the forward and left pins are supposed to work and they dont, instead of the backward and right works. So what happens is, I upload this program to my arduino and get my circuit. I plug the any of the function cables, which are forward backward, left, and right to the pins 12 and 10, and they dont work. However, when I plug the any of the cables into pins 9 and 11 which are right and backward, they work! I even tried with LED for 12 and 9 and it did not work. However, LED flashes with the pins 11 and 10. So I dont really know what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested this on more than one Arduino? My first Arduino board had a dead UART. Took me weeks and purchasing a second Arduino to figure it out. It worked well enough to not initially suspect the UART (I'm not a complete idiot). ;)

Answer (score 0):

First: turn off the old direction before turning on the new one. Now you're doing it the other way around.

Then, in your main loop you're repeating forward and left over and over. I guess you want to move forward for some time, then turn left, then move forward again, etc.
But moving forward does deactivate the reverse, but doesn't change left or right. So you're always repeating commands which haven't been changed in the first place: forward will always be active, and so will left be. You'll go in a circle, I don't know if that is the idea.

If you want to go straight, you'll probably want to turn off both left and right? Then add a delay before turning; right now your commands occur within microseconds of each other.